# Becker Robots Randomizing walls

Tags: java

Im having a problem when running my program. The program is supposed to construct a box made of walls which are supposed to cover between 5-10 Streets/avenues and with different sizes and positions everytime you run the program. Though when running it sometimes i get just 1 avenue and street or something under 5? What am i missing?

```
public class CityWalls extends Thing {

public CityWalls(City c, int st, int av, Direction d) {
    super(c, st ,av ,d);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt(11);




    int oddIncrement = 0;
    if (randomNum % 2 == 0)
    {
        oddIncrement = 1;

    }


    for (int i = 0; i < randomNum; i++) { // creating the box. 7 is the placement of the robot so he appears in the middle of the box.

            new Wall(c, i+(7-randomNum/2), (7-randomNum/2), Direction.WEST);
            new Wall(c, i+(7-randomNum/2), (7+randomNum/2) - oddIncrement, Direction.EAST);
            new Wall(c, (7-randomNum/2), i+(7-randomNum/2), Direction.NORTH);
            new Wall(c, (7+randomNum/2)-oddIncrement, i+(7-randomNum/2), Direction.SOUTH);


    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring how the creation of walls pertains to avenues and streets. A quick point though: are you intending for `(7 - randomNum) / 2` or `7 - (randomNum / 2)`? Currently, it will do the latter due to order of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
int randomNum = 5 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 5) + 1))
```

instead

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNum = rand.nextInt(11);
```

Comment: I have a follow up question if that's okey?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [Javadoc for Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), you will find that `nextInt(int n)` returns a value between `0` and `n`. What you probably want to do is `5 + rand.nextInt(6)`, as this will ensure that the range is `[5, (5 + 6)[` instead of `[0, 11[`.

Hope this helps.